# hokuyo node can not see the laser scan in rviz

Tags: ros, laser, hokuyo-node, hokuyo, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
dbb@ubuntu-dbb:~$ rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find hokuyo_node`/hokuyo_test.vcg[ INFO] 
[ERROR] [1322120397.245512167]: No techniques available for material [PointCloudMaterial0Billboard]
[ERROR] [1322120397.312309781]: No techniques available for material [PointCloudMaterial0Billboard]
[ WARN] [1322120397.466217922]: Message from [/hokuyo_node] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser].
```

This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.
This message will only print once.
File radeon_swtcl.c function r100_swtcl_flush line 323
Rendering was 1 commands larger than predicted size. We might overflow  command buffer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12076/hokuyo-node-can-not-see-the-laser-scan-in-rviz/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The material errors you are getting is because Ogre (rendering engine of rviz) cannot render the pointcloud material on your graphics hardware. Maybe try upgrading your driver or your hardware. Alternatively you can try to change the material definition, maybe you find something that works with your hardware.

Check the Ogre.log file, it should contain more information on the error.

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2011-11-28**:
thank you very much! I made it after I changed a better computer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it really necessary to start rviz with that config file?
Cant you just start rviz normally (rosrun rviz rviz), add an laser scan display with topic /laser and "Style" points (might help to get around the billboard error) and set the fixed frame to laser (or whatever the hokuyo-node publishes as transform)?

But i agree with LiMuBei in that you should also try to sort out the basic problem with rviz using his advice.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1